# how to use resource file in drawable file(like vector file)

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp"
android:alpha="0.5"
android:viewportWidth="24"
android:viewportHeight="24">
<path
    android:fillColor="?attr/colorOnSurface"
    android:pathData="M12,3c-4.97,0 -9,4.03 -9,9s4.03,9 9,9c0.83,0 1.5,-0.67 1.5,-1.5 0,-0.39 -0.15,-0.74 -0.39,-1.01 -0.23,-0.26 -0.38,-0.61 -0.38,-0.99 0,-0.83 0.67,-1.5 1.5,-1.5L16,16c2.76,0 5,-2.24 5,-5 0,-4.42 -4.03,-8 -9,-8zM6.5,12c-0.83,0 -1.5,-0.67 -1.5,-1.5S5.67,9 6.5,9 8,9.67 8,10.5 7.33,12 6.5,12zM9.5,8C8.67,8 8,7.33 8,6.5S8.67,5 9.5,5s1.5,0.67 1.5,1.5S10.33,8 9.5,8zM14.5,8c-0.83,0 -1.5,-0.67 -1.5,-1.5S13.67,5 14.5,5s1.5,0.67 1.5,1.5S15.33,8 14.5,8zM17.5,12c-0.83,0 -1.5,-0.67 -1.5,-1.5S16.67,9 17.5,9s1.5,0.67 1.5,1.5 -0.67,1.5 -1.5,1.5z" />
```

This is my icon file. I want to use resource in **android:alpha="0.5"**

just like **android:alpha="@integer/..."**

But I need to use float value ,  so the @integer/...  doesn't adapt to me .

So I want to know what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your value in **res/values/dimens.xml** like this:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="key_text_size">24sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="some_size">0.52</dimen>
</resources>
```

And use it in your vector:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:tint="#000000"
    android:alpha="@dimen/some_size"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
...
```

Comment: Oh！ thanks! At the beginning, when I entered @ the IDE only gave me the prompt of @ integer, which made me think that I could only use @ integer